# Pandas iterrows change the type of columns to float. How to cast it back to original type?

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas iterrows change the type of columns. According to [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3566) github issue, it is an intended behavior.

Any idea of a pythonic and elegant way of casting it back to the original type?
Note that I have multiple column types.

minimal example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([range(5), range(5)])
df.iloc[:,1] = df.iloc[:,1].astype('float')
for row in df.iterrows():
    print row
```

Results with

```
(0, 0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    4.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64)
(1, 0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    4.0
Name: 1, dtype: float64)
```

Note that `df.dtypes` returns the types of columns, however, I couldn't think of an elegant way of using it to cast the row back to that type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using `df.itertuples` instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([range(5), range(5)], columns=list('abcde'))
df.iloc[:,1] = df.iloc[:,1].astype('float')

for row in df.itertuples():
    print(row)

Pandas(Index=0, a=0, b=1.0, c=2, d=3, e=4)
Pandas(Index=1, a=0, b=1.0, c=2, d=3, e=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this iteration keeping the data type in the following way:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'ints': list(range(5)), 'floats': [float(i) for i in range(5)]})
print(df)
for idx in df.index:
    print(f'Integer number: {df.loc[idx,"ints"]}')
    print(f'Float number: {df.loc[idx,"floats"]}')
```

The output (in Python 3.8.5) is

```
   ints  floats
0     0     0.0
1     1     1.0
2     2     2.0
3     3     3.0
4     4     4.0
Integer number: 0
Float number: 0.0
Integer number: 1
Float number: 1.0
Integer number: 2
Float number: 2.0
Integer number: 3
Float number: 3.0
Integer number: 4
Float number: 4.0
```

Comment: confirmed behavior also in Python 3.6, and 3.7. thanks!